# Should one person have multiple answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

This question came up in regards to my comment on [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/9/how-to-improve-very-loopy-method/17#17).

If somebody has two different approaches for reviewing a piece of code, should they combine them into one answer, or have separate answers?

Answer (score 15):

I would say that you should make `n` posts for `n` solutions. 
One solution might be better than another, then everyone has a chance to upvote that specific answer.

Comment: I agree with Zolomon. I think it's better for the asker to see a range of different approaches to solve a problem.

Comment: What happens when OP takes your suggestions? Does he modify his post and everyone goes along with new suggestions? Is it time for a new question (with very similar code)? Does he leave the post unchanged, so people can offer small variations of the same ideas over and over?

Comment: Soltions? It's code review, it's suggestions for improvements, often. I usually have many separate suggestions... should I split these up in separate answers? I'd end up with 3-4 answers on each post. Sure, might give me points, but... Nyah.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: If you have a chain of solutions that are related I would go with one long answer. But if you are providing solutions from different perspectives (unless you're comparing the two), I'd go with the N-N-suggestion. IMHO.

Comment: But this is code review. It's not solutions to problems, that's SO. I typically have several completely unrelated improvements. No related chains, no different perspectives. That's what the question is about as far as I can tell.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: I see your point.. I've seen different approaches on how to go about the code review. Some do iterations in their questions. Some leave it be. If there's an interation - then I see both pros and cons with having multiple answers, one per iteration, or one huge post with a iterated suggestions included. I think we need more input on this (at least I do.)

Answer (score 11):

Only if the suggestions are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a more recent way to look at things (Not saying that the ones from 2 years ago are wrong)

To avoid "Facebook scroller long" answers, [it is OK to post multiple answers](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1053/should-we-merge-multiple-answers-from-the-same-person).

If you want to mention a lot of stuff in your answer (such as coding conventions, variable names, method length, code duplication, use of exceptions, use of public APIs...), it is often more useful to split the answer into multiple answers.