# Is there a limit to the number of answers a user can post to one single question?

Tags: discussion, answers, site-policy

### Example situation<sup>1</sup>

We have a user that finds a question and posts an answer for each and every change they would make - commonly being a single low-hanging fruit point, but not limited to it. It leads to answers that, in all, sum to a couple of sentences of value per answer. The answerer also posted a significant number of answers - enough for a full day's worth of HNQ exposure.

This can lead to a lot of "fluff" / unnecessary information - just repeats of the user ID, edit buttons, comment sections, paragraphs between answers, etc. This makes what could be half a page of answers span a couple of pages.

---

To me it just feels off. To simplify the following questions I'll refer to this as 'flooding'. And so I have the following questions:

- Is 'flooding' allowed?

  If it is allowed:

  - What effects do you think allowing 'flooding' would have on answer quality?

  If it's not allowed:

  - At what point does answering become 'flooding'?
  - How should we deal with 'flooding'?
  - Should users post a [frequently posted comment](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4952)? If so, what and where?

---

<sup>1</sup> This question was sparked by a [specific example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/174263), however the situation isn't limited to it.

Comment: That specific example is clearly abuse IMO, and will be discussed among the mod team. Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: @Mat'sMug What specifically constitutes abuse in this very example?

Comment: @benrudgers see my answer below. *The first thing that comes to mind is "this user is trying to somehow abuse the system to farm upvotes, badges, and reputation score."*

Comment: @Mat'sMug I read your answer before commenting.  It is generic and does not describe what constitutes abuse in the actual answer. My answer to follow.

Comment: That quoted block at the top was specifically aimed at that specific case.

Comment: @Mat'sMug 1. See my answer. 2. The evidence of vote farming would be from voting patterns. 3. The goal of the site is to provide useful information, not to stamp out possible moderation problems on a 1% probability.

Comment: Voting patterns tell us about how a user *spends* their votes, or how/whether a group of users form a voting ring. Voting patterns have nothing to do with this.

Comment: I don't think a *frequently posted comment* is necessary as this behavior is not that frequent.

Comment: @SimonForsberg I agree with this not being a frequent thing. However it may become frequent (Hopefully not). But mostly it was just to plan for the future, so I know what to do / say if I come across it again. :)

Comment: While behaviour like this isn't frequent, I've seen it done by multiple users. Thanks for bringing it up so we can establish a clear, community-based policy on the matter.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> ```
> <moderator-hat>
> ```
>
> The first thing that comes to mind is "this user is trying to somehow
>   abuse the system to farm upvotes, badges, and reputation score."
>
> Because yes, people do that. All the time. And when you *look* like
>   you're abusing the system, chances are people will think you *are*
>   abusing the system.
>
> And abusing the system leads to all kinds of not-fun things nobody
>   wants to go through.
>
> ```
> </moderator-hat>
> ```

---

## Is "Flooding" allowed?

I don't think it should. But I'm a moderator - I don't *make* the rules, I *enforce* them. Let this community decide.

#### At what point does answering becomes "flooding"?

When two or more short answers could reasonably be merged into one, single, longer answer. I think this can't be a hard line drawn in the sand; there's always going to be a "gray zone", but when you're looking at 3+ answers that each point out a different thing about the OP's code, and you think to yourself "why aren't these answers just sub-headings of one-and-the-same answer?", then you're probably looking at "flooding".

#### How should we deal with "flooding"?

If community consensus is that flooding isn't allowed, then standard moderation rules apply: custom-flag one of the answers, user will be contacted privately and, depending on what follows, expect edits and deletions.

#### Should users post a *frequently posted comment*? If so what and where?

Maybe link to this very question in a comment under one of the flooding answers?

---

## About long answers...

Long, detailed answers are *normal* on this site. While the rest of the Stack Exchange network limits post length to ~30K characters, on Code Review the post length limit is *doubled*, to ~60K characters. There's a reason for this, and it's because long answers are here to stay.

#### So... where's the line?

There isn't *One True Way* to write up a peer review, and we don't want one either. But I believe we all agree that posting 3, 4, 5, 6 or more answers on a single question is abusive.

The line, to me, is here:

---

^ that's the line. It's 3 characters in markdown: `---` and you have a line. And that line can - *and should* be used to split relatively unrelated aspects of an answer.

The point is that, a **properly formatted** post can be very long, and *still* be an amazing read. Use [markdown formatting help](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if you're not sure how to format your answers.

---

## But are multiple, short answers ok?

It was suggested [in the past](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20/23788) that separate answers are absolutely fine if they're **mutually exclusive**. I like that suggestion very much, but I don't think that's the *be-all-end-all* solution.

We don't want reviewers to think they *have* to write long answers to *post* an answer on CR - **obviously**, short answers are perfectly fine: they stand on their own and if that's all a reviewer says on a question, it's fine too.

But if you're reviewing code and find that you have multiple *points*, it doesn't mean you have multiple *answers*.

- An
- Answer
- Can
- Very
- Well
- Make
- Multiple
- Points

---

- Even
- When
- They're
- Not

---

- All
- Related

See?

---

### Debunking

(in response to [this answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8433/23788))

- > *the majority of people refuse reading long, not very good structured texts.*

  Correct. That's why when you post a long answer, you **format it properly** and structure it appropriately. Or when you come across a poorly structured/formatted long answer, you can always edit it to improve it. The solution is proper formatting, not multiple answers.
- > *There may be a problem quickly scan a long one for yet not known things for me whereas in answers addressing only one issue is easier distinguish if I will skip it or read it carefully.*

  Again, proper formatting. With proper headings, I can skip all the nitpicking stuff and quickly jump to the meat of a well-structured answer.
- > *There are cases when the code in the question is so poor that the only acceptable solution is to completely rewrite it.*

  I often do this: top part of my answer reviews OP's code as written, and the bottom part explains a complete rewrite, using a completely different approach.

  If the actual peer review is long enough, it can very well stand on its own - and then the alternate solution could very well stand on its own as well, with proper explanations of why and how that alternate solution is better than the OP's. **This *is* a good, valid reason to split up an answer!**
- > *every answer has a "share" link - and I prefer to share the explanation of only one particular thing of my interest, not lost in huge bunch of other information.*

  That isn't a justification for *flooding* a post with multiple, short answers: it's a work-around that [poorly] mitigates the lack of hash-links for H1/H2/H3 headings in Stack Exchange posts - and that is entirely an implementation detail of how Markdown is getting rendered on the site, and is entirely subject to change in the future.

  Nothing forbids making a well-backed-up [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) on CR Meta, or even Meta Stack Exchange, to ask that the Markdown renderer starts turning `<h1>` into `<div id="section-title"><h1>` so that hash-links can work.

  Posting multiple answers to circumvent that lacking feature, is not a good solution.
- > *The reason for a nice formatting answer is to make it attractive and readable*

  Bingo. And it's also the weapon of choice to turn long, boring, wall-of-text answers into pure awesomeness.

Comment: Would be nice if we could have `#[Plain Text Title as normal](some-anchor-text)` render the H1 (or whatever) as an anchored header with a #name that is linkable. (But that's a feature request for SE.)

Comment: @EBrown yes, that's exactly what I'm suggesting =)

Comment: On second thought - that wouldn't work unless a `Regex` was used to ensure that `some-anchor-text` was not a link elsewhere. Maybe `#[Plain Text Title as Normal](#some-anchor-text)` where the `#` in the parenthesis is the magic test. Might work more effectively. Probably wasn't done yet because Documentation was supposed to solve that.

Comment: @EBrown IDK, but GitHub seems to have no problem with Markdown generating hash-links for `## Headings`.

Comment: That depends on how they generate it I guess - I would see `#[...](...)` being a problem as that *may also* be indicating a regular hyperlink. Either way, [there's a feature-request on big-Meta for exactly this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37894/support-anchor-names-in-posts) that's not status-tagged. Wonder if it should be refreshed with the new sunset of Documentation?

Comment: That's 7 years and 7 months old. I think it needs a refresher. @EBrown I just put up a +100 bounty on it.

Comment: [Apparently Jon Ericson would like to see this happen as well.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37894/support-anchor-names-in-posts?noredirect=1#comment975945_37894)

Comment: @EBrown FWIW that's no moderator - he's a Community Manager =)

Comment: That may be true, but based on the history of SE, I *really* don't expect this to ever be implemented. I think we can hope and dream all we want, but let's face it: this isn't important enough to warrant *building their own spec that might change*. We won't see it **until** it's standardized because SE doesn't want to have to make a change of it later.

Comment: @EBrown regardless, my point holds: don't split up answers just because SE didn't implement anchor headings as of yet.

Comment: Totally agree - just don't want anyone getting their hopes up that this will happen anytime soon.

Comment: Would you be willing to answer a couple of my questions above - if you think they are relevant? I asked them so non-diamond 'moderators' can help ease moderation. I for example don't know what avenue I should use to help moderation if I come across something like this again - chat; flags on question, or answers; meta; or comments on answer, or answers.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I don't think "flooding" should be allowed; the line is drawn when multiple answers can be combined into one given proper formatting, and IMO if community consensus is that "flooding" shouldn't be allowed, then the standard moderation rules apply, from mod-message warning to account suspension - so yeah, custom-flag is appropriate. I'm tempted to ask a similar question on MSE to see what the point of view is of the SE community as a whole. But I'm just a moderator, I don't get to decide what the rules are, I'm just here to enforce them. I think non-diamond users should decide that.

Comment: What is normal on StackOverflow today, is not what was normal a few years ago. Sites evolve. Moderation that assumes long literary answers as the norm is a barrier to non-native English users. There are established methods of dealing with flooding. There is nothing 'conversational' in the case in question here.

Comment: @benrudgers if a non-native English user can write up 5 answers on one question, then they can write up 5 line-separated points in one answer, and the system will generate an auto-flag after 20 comments. With 5 answers the system will generate 5 auto-flags after 100 comments.

Comment: *I believe we all agree that posting 3, 4, 5, 6 or more answers on a single question is abusive.* It is true you believe that. The content of the belief is false due to the content of my belief.

Comment: @benrudgers if posting 3+ answers on one question isn't obnoxious behavior that's **obviously** opening the door to vote-farming to you, then good for you and you can run for moderator when it becomes community consensus and I step down for not wanting to put up with this crap. FWIW it's completely unfair to the users that *do* make the effort of properly formatting their own legit, multi-point answers.

Comment: @Mat'sMug My opinion is that it does not require moderation. Your opinion is that it does. It's entirely your choice to spend energy moderating on this issue. It's not why I voted for you. It's not enough to make me vote against you. If you don't like being a moderator, don't keep doing it for my sake. Good luck.

Answer (score 9):

> Is 'flooding' allowed?

I vote for NO, let's not allow this.

> At what point does answering become 'flooding'?

When two answers (of the same user) don't conflict.
That is, two answers conflict when it would be unreasonable to upvote both at the same time.
Only then, it makes sense to split.
Otherwise, it's flooding.

> How should we deal with 'flooding'?

Flag for moderator attention, with a comment "flooding",
and mods can manually merge the answers.

#### Debunking [MarianD's answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8433/12390)

**TL;DR**

If the answers don't contradict each other,
then it would be easier to read them in one post,
with good headings, and hopefully ordered by some logic.
It's harder to read when fragmented, displayed in random order,
and interleaved with answers by other users.

---

> From my personal experience the majority of people refuse reading long, not very good structured texts. This is the first reason for splitting long answer into a few shorter.

I agree that the majority of people do not like reading long texts.
The users of this site are not like that,
they are not representative of the general population.

> The second motivation for shorter answers is to provide information not only to OP but also to other people reading individual answers. There may be a problem quickly scan a long one for yet not known things for me whereas in answers addressing only one issue is easier distinguish if I will skip it or read it carefully.

I think it's easier to scan texts author by author.
Every author has a different mindset and writing style.
When there are multiple answers by multiple users,
the switch between styles can be a real mental burden.

Another important point is the ordering.
For example, I often address very different facets of the posted code,
such as algorithm, design, usability, best practices.
The order in which I write these sections is never random.
It's deliberate.
Sometimes I order things from most important to less important.
Other times, for beginners,
I go from easy to complex.
Sometimes I also cross-reference by section names.
The ordering and structure is very important for me.
And if I split my answers, I would lose control over that.

> The fourth reason (and there exist even more ones) is than every answer has a "share" link - and I prefer to share the explanation of only one particular thing of my interest, not lost in huge bunch of other information.

That may be convenient for *you*,
but not for the vast majority of users of this site.
And I think that they should be your main target audience.

> The reason for a nice formatting answer is to make it attractive and readable - like for the reviewed code itself.

As I explained earlier,
a split answer is not more attractive and not more readable.
I think it's the opposite.
And as far as formatting nicely,
it works precisely the same way,
whether you split answers or not.

> But the main, the most important thing is that the goal of answers should be to help other, less experienced people. Not to express myself, not to save space, not to show more experienced people as I'm good, not to correct every one thing. And it is not possible without adapting to OP (estimated) level.

And if that is your true goal, I suggest to follow my counter-points and recommendations above.

Answer (score 7):

There were originally five answers from @MarianD:

1. [PEP 8 formatting](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/174269/9357)
2. [Replacing `while i < len(text)` loop with `for c in text`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/174270/9357)
3. [Use `.format()` instead of calling `print()` with multiple arguments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/174273/9357)
4. [Reusing the `j = ord(text[i])` intermediate result](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/174274/9357)
5. [Seeking clarification on the usage of `text_data()`, and suggesting that there might be a solution involving `number = int(text)`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/174277/9357)

I've taken some actions on them:

- Answers 2, 3, and 4 were all short remarks about improving the loop, and would be better presented as one coherent answer.  I've incorporated all of the advice into answer 2, and deleted answers 3 and 4.
- Answer 5 was converted to Community Wiki status with this comment from me:

  > This "answer" is, in part, asking for clarification, and as such, is a comment that is too long to fit in a standard comment. (By the way, that isn't how the code actually behaves.) – 200_success♦ 2017-08-29 18:54:39Z

  @MarianD subsequently deleted the answer voluntarily.

That leaves us with two answers, one about PEP 8 formatting, and another one about how to express the loop better.  I've left them as separate posts, since the advice is largely independent of each other.

Answer (score 5):

I think we may limit the amount of answers a user can give by the content of their answers; that is, posting a new answer for what could be a subsection of one long answer is not allowed, but answering once and adding a follow-up answer with more in-depth information may be allowed, if there is a clear distinction in content between the two.

Allowing 'flooding' would make it harder to review the quality of answers, because there's no way to select all answers as the 'best answer' at once.

Comment: Agreed. As a side note, an example of what I consider a "good second answer" is found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/109255/84718).

Comment: Great example, that's exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 4):

Let me first quote some answers to a similiar question

[200_sucess: Should we merge multiple answers from the same person?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1064/29371)

> I don't think that length should be a criterion for splitting answers.
>   The considerations should be
>
> - Independence: Can this answer stand on its own? Is it a suggestion that other users might upvote or downvote depending on their opinion?
> - Coherence: Would grouping multiple points together convey your thoughts more effectively?

[Mat's Mug: Should we merge multiple answers from the same person?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1057/29371)

> I agree with @SimonAndréForsberg, this isn't about the numbers, it's
>   about the quality of what we're posting. Quality is king. If CR starts
>   having tons of low-quality answers, the answer ratio could be 10
>   answers per questions, the site wouldn't be in a better shape.

[Simon Forsberg: Should we merge multiple answers from the same person?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1056/29371)

> I do think however that we should avoid "Facebook scroller
>   long"-answers. Answers should be easy to read. Of course there are
>   some answers who are both long and easy to read, and that's fine.
>   There are however, answers which brings up many different aspects from
>   the original question (coding conventions, variable names, method
>   length, code duplication, use of exceptions, use of public APIs...),
>   and many of those is more useful to split into two separate answers.

---

In my opinion both is fine. Having one long answer, like I prefer to write, or having multiple short answers won't matter as long as the quality is given and they can stand on their own.

**But** if I see more than two answers from the same user I would most likely only place an upvote on one of them although all 5 (or 6...) answers are good/valid but short ones.

We shouldn't limit the number of answers a single user can post for a single question but we should place a comment stating that long answers are fine as well, maybe back-linking to this question. If we do this consequently we may increase the quality of the answers and avoid rep-whoring (which isn't a problem on CR right now).

For this specific question I would have prefered one answer where the single points would be formatted using headlines or horizontal rules.

Answer (score -8):

I am going to focus on the specific example.

- I do not see any evidence of abuse.
- I do not see any answers that are low quality, not an answer, etc. that warrant a downvote.
- I do not see anything in the specific example that warrants moderator attention.

Could the system be abused using the pattern of multiple short answers by a single user? Yeah, of course...and the system can be abused without using the pattern. The key is not a specific pattern but the inclination of an individual to act in bad faith. I think the assumption of bad faith here borders on injustice. There simply is no evidence of any actual harm to the site or the community.

#### The facts

Because each individual answer is constructive and stands on its own.

Nobody else is answering the question. So what if it is not how I would answer if I wrote an answer I am not going to write? The answers are there for the person asking and mostly for people stumbling upon them via search. Those arriving at the answer via search are unlikely to be less informed due to the format.

#### My take

Personally, there are a number of requests for review where I have thought I could provide a good review, but I don't seem willing to muster up a couple of hours writing a comprehensive, sourced, and entertaining review.  So though I look at the answers and still think, that's not how I would do it; I see it as an approach that might allow me to provide sound review comments in circumstances where I'm not energized enough to write at length.

Sites evolve. They can evolve toward diversity or in some other direction. If there is a quality problem with the answers, the first order tool is down voting. I am not saying that the pattern does not merit monitoring. I am saying the evidence provided does not justify moderator intervention. It is ok to look and see where it goes. It is ok to be uncertain.

Different is not bad.

Comment: We're Stack Exchange, a Q&A network. IMO "Flooding" creates the false impression that it's ok to turn Code Review into a discussion forum. I believe *that* is how the behavior is harmful, intentional abuse or not. CR *already* deviates quite a bit from SE's Q&A model; what we've been doing for *years* has worked very well so far, and got our eternal-beta site graduated after months and months and months of efforts. I feel changing the proven Q&A model is dangerous, and threatening.

Comment: @Mat'sMug There is no evidence that that is the intent of the answers. More importantly, there is no evidence that that is the **effect** of the answers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerry_Pournelle#Iron_Law_of_Bureaucracy

Comment: Sure, except the day it's "proven" that the behavior harms the site, it's too late, we're already doomed.

Comment: @Mat'sMug, No the day it harms the site is the day it is a problem that needs to be addressed using the tools that exist to address it.

Comment: And I believe this behavior could be harming the site, and we're here today to address it.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Back to my first question. What exactly is the harm **here**?

Comment: I'd like to point out that this doesn't answer the question. It's not about the specific case - it's just an example point, and the reason I asked. Two of your three points have no relevance IMO to this discussion - I never said there was abuse, and last time I checked there were no votes on their answers. Up or down.

Comment: The harm for me is reduced readability. I find it easier to read one well-structured answer of a user, rather than his thoughts randomly scattered. Not organizing and ordering the review comments looks like a lack of care about readers. To me, the split-answer format is inferior, and not recommended, for the sake of the readers.

Comment: @janos the harm is also the unfairness of one user obnoxiously posting 5 answers and collecting +50 for one upvote on each, whereas the honest user that makes the effort of properly formatting their multi-point answers and get +10 for one upvote.

Comment: @Mat'sMug People post answers to help and to get internet points. Getting points is part of what makes the site fun. It is part of what makes the site work. How many points one person gets does not effect how many points another person gets. The purpose of having moderators is not to prevent people from getting points. Pretty much any reasonable answer is probably worth fifty points. Many get zero. It's just internet points.

Comment: question: @benrudgers do / did you see the two deleted answers by the same user?

Comment: @Vogel612 I lack the ability to see deleted answers. If the user deleted the answers on their own, then the system works. If a moderator deleted the answers, then that would be evidence to support the opinion that the example is an example of an actual problem.

Comment: A moderator deleted two answers and merged them into another answer, using `---` to separate the blocks of separate answers.

Comment: @Vogel612 Oh. Yes, I saw it before. I think the edit was just busy work. I don't think it solved any actual problem. I don't think it improves the internet. I don't think it makes CodeReview better in the short term. I think it reduces the potential for improvement via evolution. I think it makes the site more like one a bulletin board where a lot of energy is spent toward creating insiders and outsiders...something Spolsky and Atwood were trying to avoid by the design of StackExchange.

Comment: @benrudgers I actually don't follow ... Would you mind dropping by in [chat] so we can discuss somewhere not the comments?

Comment: @Vogel612 I think the rapidity with which the edits were made illustrates the degree to which *different* is equated with *wrong* on the site.

Comment: The edits were made after **16 hours** which is not what I'd call "rapid" and also after the owner of the answers had responded (and been responded to again) as well as after the establishment of a preliminary "Stimmungsbild" (literally "mood picture")

Comment: @Vogel612 The edits did not improve the site. They are moderation for the sake of moderation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64771/discussion-between-vogel612-and-ben-rudgers).